# If value not equal in cmake 2.8

Tags: cmake

**Short version:** I have build options that only work on one platform. The `autotools` file I'm converting form has a check of the form `if test "$platform_linux" != "yes"`. Can I do the same thing in my `CMakeLists.txt` (test if the value is NOT equal)?

**Slightly longer version:** I've got a test for various platforms following the advice found [here](http://www.openguru.com/2009/04/cmake-detecting-platformoperating.html):

```
IF(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Linux")
    # Linux specific code
    SET(OperatingSystem "Linux")
ENDIF(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Linux")
```

I'd like to do a test of the form `IF(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} NOT MATCHES "Linux")`. This doesn't appear to work, and the only documentation I can find is a mailing-list post from 2002, which suggests the `NOT` isn't valid for `cmake` prior to `1.2`. [[Link](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2002-January/002597.html)].

Is this still the case in later `cmake` versions, specifically `2.6` and/or `2.8`?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You're close!  The correct syntax for [`IF`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command:if) is

```
IF(NOT <expression>)
```

So in your specific case, you want

```
IF(NOT ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Linux")
```

Comment: Important addition about quotes.  if string can be interpreted as a list, then it must be in quotes. e.g. set(pets "cat; dog; fish");  IF(NOT "${pets}" MATCHES ".*dog,*") works, but not  IF(NOT ${pets} MATCHES ".*dog,*")